# django-registration: how do I check whether the user is logged in before displaying a page

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-registration

I followed [this page](http://www.michelepasin.org/blog/2011/01/14/setting-up-django-registration/) to set up a django registration site. It's pretty awesome, and registration and authentication are nicely wrapped.

But, it doesn't show me, how do I check if a user is logged in, who this user is, before displaying a webpage? and how do I direct the user to a new page after logged in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In a view, you can use `if request.user.is_authenticated():` and the variable for the current user is `request.user`

In a template, you can use `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` and the variable for the current user is `user`

For redirecting a user after logging in, you can set up `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` variable in `settings.py`

Comment: in the view, remember that is_authenticated() is a method, not an attribute.  If you check request.user.is_authenticated in the view, then you'll always get true.

Answer (score 7):

**In .py documents**

You can either use this inside every view

```
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
   #do something
```

or this just before every view

```
@login_required
```

Remember that this one requires importing `from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required`
and you may also want to write `LOGIN_URL = "/loginurl/"` in your `settings.py` to get non-logged users redirected to an specific URL instead of the default one `accounts/login`)

**In .html documents**

```
{% if not user.is_authenticated %}
Login is required
{% endif %}
```

---

**Redirecting after logging in**

You can either modify `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in `settings.py`

or `redirect("/indexpage")` after the user has been logged in.
This last one requires importing `from django.shortcuts import redirect`

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a login required decorator before your view :

```
@login_required()
```

It redirects a user to the login page if a non logged in user tries to access your view

You will find more on this page :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization